# Authentication token expired impact on output stream

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection, access-token

I am establishing connection `HttpURLConnection httpCon` based on authentication token. And create `OutputStream out`  using following way:
    //Init

```
// Account account is created (joss.model.Account)
Access mAccess = account.authenticate();
String mToken = mAccess.getToken() 

String getAuthToken()
{
  return mToken; 
}

HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
httpCon.addRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", getAuthToken());
httpCon.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
httpCon.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setChunkedStreamingMode(STREAMING_CHUNK);
OutputStream out   = httpCon.getOutputStream();

//Thread.sleep(expireTime * 1.2);
out.write("Data".getBytes()); //write to a file
out.close
```

The authentication token expires after several mins. If I comment `Thread.sleep(ExpireTime * 1.2);` everything works fine. If not and expiration time passes 
I think that I should  get `401 not authorized`, but in this case when
I try to close `OutputStream` after the token is expired I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` while closing and nothing is written eventually (File is empty).

How can I solve that?

Comment: What file? where is the code that writes to a file? Do you mean the body of the request?

Comment: I still do not see a file ("...nothing is written eventually (File is empty)")

Comment: @weston out.write("Data".getBytes());

Comment: I create URL url = new URL(getAccessURL() + "/" + fileName);//This is file. Write is done when out.write("Data".getBytes());

Comment: OK, so the http server code, which you hare not provided, creates a file on "PUT". The server is not doing this, but you are certain it is a client code problem.

Comment: But you also say you expect a 401, **and** the file is not written, "can I solve that?" If you expect a 401, is it not totally correct for the file to not be written?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111979/discussion-between-yakov-and-weston).